# Zapier frequently 10.01 seconds timeout

Tags: python, soap, python-requests, zapier

I get data from my Zap, construct a xml body of an http request from it, and send the http request to an external server, which is based on SOAP (a CRM).

the script usually runs successfully, but once in a while it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

2018-03-20T13:23:24.876Z d851674c-2c41-11e8-a905-954c98b7d8f5 Task timed out 
after 10.01 seconds
```

Why does it happen? how can I fix it? I am a paid user by the way.

Answer (score 4):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

That error is just what it sounds like - we give paid users' code steps 10 seconds each to execute (free users only get 1 second). It sounds like you're packing a lot of functionality into a single step. I'm not sure what portion of the code is taking so much time (10 seconds is a lot) but it might be worth splitting that into multiple code step if this problem persists.

Comment: 10 seconds is not that much if you're calling an external server, which may be a bit slow.

Comment: I agree, 10s is not a LOT