# Zapier - Timeout errors 10.01

Tags: javascript, zapier

For several days now, Zapier has been sending me alerts to my e-mail account about an error related to one of the Facebook forms that we have associated with our website and CRM system (RMS).

This happens every time someone submits a form in response to a Facebook ad. I get the following error:

`Task timed out after 10.01 seconds`

I don't really understand what happening and not so good in coding too, but I manage Facebook Ads and have full access to Zapier panel.

Could you help me and give me some advice in this matter? There's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388892/zapier-frequently-10-01-seconds-timeout) that has the same problem as me. The answer there is:

> That error is just what it sounds like - we give paid user's code steps 10 seconds each to execute (free users only get 1 second). It sounds like you're packing a lot of functionality into a single step. I'm not sure what portion of the code is taking so much time (10 seconds is a lot) but it might be worth splitting that into multiple code step if this problem persists.

How can I split this step here? Could you help me with my code?

```js
var input = {
  token: "c3a3df65-80fe-49cd-ac9e-32a5a5324bc4",
  channelId: inputData.channel_id,
  offerId: inputData.offer_id,
  wantStartWorkImmediately: true,
  agreement: {
    privacyPolicy: true,
    applicationType: "SINGLE",
    cvProcessing: false,
    marketingPool: false,
    aiProcessing: false,
    marketingBigData: false,
  },
  name: inputData.full_name,
};
if (inputData.email && inputData.email.length > 0) {
  input["email"] = inputData.email;
}
if (inputData.phone_number && inputData.phone_number.length > 0) {
  input["phone"] = inputData.phone_number;
}
if (
  inputData.data_processing &&
  inputData.data_processing.search("yes") != -1
) {
  input["agreement"]["applicationType"] = "MULTIPLE";
  input["agreement"]["policyCompanyIds"] = [
    17345726,
    17345727,
    17345728,
    17345729,
    17345730,
    17345731,
    29612586,
    71537568,
    17345725,
    -10101,
  ];
}
if (inputData.ai_processing && inputData.ai_processing.search("yes") != -1) {
  input["agreement"]["aiProcessing"] = true;
}
if (inputData.cv_processing && inputData.cv_processing.search("yes") != -1) {
  input["agreement"]["cvProcessing"] = true;
}
if (
  inputData.marketing_big_data &&
  inputData.marketing_big_data.search("yes") != -1
) {
  input["agreement"]["marketingBigData"] = true;
}
if (inputData.marketing_pool && inputData.marketing_pool.search("yes") != -1) {
  input["agreement"]["marketingPool"] = true;
}
if (inputData.privacy_policy && inputData.privacy_policy.search("yes") != -1) {
  input["agreement"]["privacyPolicy"] = true;
}
const response = await fetch(
  "https://rms.workservice.pl/dashboard/api/landing-page/v2/register-account",
  {
    body:
      '$------WebKitFormBoundarypKVXozgIjDQAnR50\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="request"\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n\n\n' +
      JSON.stringify(input) +
      "\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarypKVXozgIjDQAnR50--\r\n",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type":
        "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarypKVXozgIjDQAnR50",
    },
    method: "POST",
  }
);
if (response.status !== 200) {
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log("status != 200");
  console.log(json);
  input["errors"] = json.fieldErrors;
} else {
  input["errors"] = "ok";
}
return input;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zapier frequently 10.01 seconds timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388892/zapier-frequently-10-01-seconds-timeout)

Comment: They just blocked my Zap, because of that. Does anybody got any answers and could help me?

Your Zap titled "ZAP NAME" has been turned off because we're getting repeated errors nearly every time we try to run it.

The last error message was "2021-05-06T22:59:42.496Z 4dbb28f9-16e4-466d-b5e9-19987e33a296 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds".

Comment: After several failuare of Zaps, zapier turn off Zap, so fix the issue with the action. for more  details check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388892/zapier-frequently-10-01-seconds-timeout

Comment: Thank you Kishor for your answer. I saw that post, but I don't really get it how i can split this code. Could you help me with my code? I just edit the post and paste it

Comment: Nobody can't help me?

Comment: If you run this code locally, does the API call to `workservice` take a long time (10+) to return? If so, you may need to explore other options than running this code in Zapier.